# What is the black connector called?

Tags: vga, cable, display-adapter

I am having trouble identifying one of the connectors on the cable in the images below. The blue connector should be a male VGA connector, but I've no idea what the black one is. If I was to take a guess I would say mini-display, but the connector casing(?) is shaped similarly to the vga connector. I've tried doing a google image search and looking at all the different types of connectors, but I cannot identify it. What is the black connector type?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What device does it connect to?

Comment: I expect a graphics card or a monitor.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because picture guessing problems are generally not useful to other readers due to there being no way to search for the thread and its answers.  See [Are hardware (port, cable, etc.) visual identification questions allowed or not?](https://meta.superuser.com/q/7647/364367)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a [D-Terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-Terminal) connector. They are typically found on Japanese consumer electronics.

So, you've got a VGA to D-Terminal cable.